# How to resize a scroll composite to always fit its contents horizontally?

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have a scrolled composite ,it contains a tableViewer.
My requirement is that if the table is increased in width,the scroll composite should not show horizontal scroll ,but it should expand to fit table's size.
The only reason I have used a scrolled composite here is I want to show vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to control the scrollbars of a `Table` in SWT - which is a sub-class of `Scrollable` - simply add one or more of the following styles in the constructor. If you construct a Viewer, the same styles are used.

`SWT.H_SCROLL`

> Style constant for horizontal scrollbar behavior

`SWT.V_SCROLL`

> Style constant for vertical scrollbar behavior

`SWT.NO_SCROLL`

> Style constant for no scrollbar behavior
>
> When neither H_SCROLL or V_SCROLL are specified, controls are free to create the default scroll bars for the control. Using NO_SCROLL overrides the default and forces the control to have no scroll bars.

Comment: My problem is when I resize the table the parent copmosite is not resizing accordingly,but it is trimming the table ie it doesnot show full table.

Comment: What is the used layout of the parent `Composite`? Consider use 
`GridLayout` and a `GridData(FILL, TOP, true, false)` for the table itself.